# How to get best admob size for current screen configuration?

Tags: android, size, admob, adview

### Background

I wish to show an ad using admob on my app, but I also wish to show there something while it is being loaded (before it's being shown) or maybe even when there is no internet connection.

### The problem

It seems that admob has a wide range of sizes for its ads, depending on the screen (link [here](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#android)) you wish to target, but there is no instruction of what you should use for choosing the best size .

For example, they talk about tablets , but they don't define what is a tablet in the table, and of which type. They don't even explain what each of the ad types mean.

### The question

Given a device with a specific configuration, how should I choose the best size of the adView?

If I use BANNER, will it always be shown? Will it automatically choose the others in case the screen has enough space?

Comment: Did you figure out how to show something while the ad is being loaded?

Comment: @RuchirBaronia No. Sadly no.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using different ad sizes for the four different screen sizes (small, normal, large, xlarge). IMO it makes sense to use more screen real estate for ads on larger screens and less on smaller screens but that depends a lot on the app and how much of the screen real-estate you are willing to trade in for larger ads (larger ads = higher revenue). So it's really a question of finding the right balance between usability and maximizing ad revenue. If the ad is too large and too obtrusive, then the usability will suffer and so will the rating and thus the number of downloads. If the ad is very small (BANNER size on an xlarge screen is really very small), users won't even notice and might not click on it.

In order to use different ads formats for different screen sizes I use the include tag to include the ad layout, which I define in the layout folders layout, layout-small, layout-large and layout-xlarge. So each of these folders contains an ad.xml and they have different admob:adSize and admob:adUnitId tags.

I also reserve space on the layout should the ad not load (no network e.g.). The dimensions of the space are the dimensions of the different ad sizes:
BANNER: 320*50
IAB_BANNER: 468*60
IAB_LEADERBOARD: 728*90

I define the dimensions in dimens.xml files located in values, values-large and values-xlarge (small uses BANNER too in my apps). The dimensions can be referenced in your layout in the layout_width and layout_height tag like so:

```
android:layout_width="@dimen/admob_ad_width"
android:layout_height="@dimen/admob_ad_height"
```

Essentially it's your decision which ad sizes you want to display on what device (Admob will use the defined adSize and not override your configuration). I'm using BANNER for small and normal sized screens, IAB_BANNER for large and IAB_LEADERBOARD for xlarge screens but that decision lies with you. The approach to let Admob decide which size to display isn't a good option for most apps as they should make good use the screen real estate and knowing how large the ad will be helps a lot when it comes to designing the screen layout.

Comment: shouldn't it be better to use different qualifiers, with the available-width or available-height of DPs ? also, i asked for an advice what should be the "buckets" of which ad to put when.

Comment: What are you referring to with DPs? Do you mean different screen densities? My approach already considers screen densities. The ads will have the same size on different densities. An 350*50 ad banner will look (more or less) the same on a mdpi and an xhdpi screen. That's because the @dimen/ values will be considered as dpi values.

Comment: I changed my answer to include advice on how to pick the right ad format for different screen formats. IMO screen density shouldn't matter really because higher density doesn't make the screen larger and so it really comes down to how large the screen is and not how many pixels it has.

Comment: about screens, you probably haven't heard of the new qualifiers. i didn't talk about densities. i talked about available DPs (density pixels) . check the new category "Using new size qualifiers" on this link: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: The dp qualifiers offer you more control over the specific screen sizes your app supports than the "old" screen size qualifiers. It all depends on your app's requirements if using them makes sense. In relation to ads you asked "Given a device with a specific configuration, how should I choose the best size of the adView?". I stated my opinion that using the screen size qualifiers is good enough. If you disagree then you disagree. If think I answered both your questions and if you think otherwise, please rephrase the question.

Comment: BTW if you consider using smart banners your question is obsolete because Admob will pick the banner size. I like to have control over my screen layout and therefore I'm not using smart banners. The advantage I see in smart banners is that there are more available formats and that should result in higher ad revenue.

Comment: How does android decide about smart banners sizes? will I be notified about their size when it's ready to be used?

Comment: Android doesn't decide on smart banner sizes but the Admob SDK does. It's explained here what formats are used on which screens: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/smart-banners. If you want to know the size of the ad view you can check once the layouting processing has finished. How to do that? Now that's a whole different question and you'll find the answers here on SO.

Comment: i already know how to get a view's size. i need the size before i even start a connection, and according to what i see , it's up to me to decide which ad to use and then i will know what size i am supposed to get. i'm still not sure what are the "smart ads".

Comment: With smart banners there's no programmatic way to determine the size of the ad before it loads. There's just the table that I linked to in a previous comment. There's really no point in using smart banners if you want to know the size beforehand. It's the whole point of smart banners that you don't have to worry about the size but let the Admob SDK do it for you. If you want to know the size beforehand use my approach which gives you complete control over your screen layout.

Comment: ok then, thank you for your advice. so in short you use banner for normal screen, IAB_BANNER for large, and IAB_LEADERBOARD for xlarge, right? but don't you also want that it will change with orientation or number of available DPs ?

Comment: It all depends on your app if you need to distinguish between landscape and portrait. Portrait mode is normally easier because ads are usually at the bottom or at the top but in landscape mode it's a waste of time to use the whole width for ads so you'll have to think about away to fit the ad into your layout. This could mean to have different sizes for portrait and landscape. My approach works nicely  with different ad sizes for different orientation.

Comment: Using dps gives you - as I explained above - a more granular way to configure ad sizes depending on screen real estate. If you think a sw600dp screen needs to have a BANNER sized ad while a sw720dp screen needs IAB_BANNER then use the dp qualifiers instead of the 4 standard qualifiers. To decide what makes sense check out your competitors. If they are successful with very large ads, then go for large ads, if they have small ads then it might not be a good idea to have large ads, unless of course you have other ways to differentiate your app from theirs.

Comment: Thank you! great answer. You include about smart banners too

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use the newly introduced [AdMob Adaptive Banners](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/banner/adaptive). They don't require adjustments on your side and they utilize all the width available.

Embed them into a FrameLayout like following

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/adFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom" />
```

When no banner is loaded layout_height="wrap_content" will be 0, so the FrameLayout will be invisible to the user.